# My app not call onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onresume, onpause

my app after onPause() call onCreate(). I need after onPause() onResume().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
On this map is after onPause() two possibility, first is app process killed and onCreate(), seccond is onResume().

Comment: onResume will be called when your activity is brought back to the foreground.

Comment: What is your actual question?